# How to rollback on file import in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, commit, rollback

I have a script that creates a .sql file with several hundred thousand separate insert statements.  Then I run "mysql -u user -p dbase < import.sql.  If one of the insert statements fails, I would like to rollback everything in the .sql file.  If all the insert statements are successful, I would like to commit them.

I am not really sure how to do this?  Can anyone tell me what I need to get this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to disable autocommit as the first action of the script. By default, each statement commits automatically as soon as it is done.

```
SET autocommit=OFF;

INSERT INTO ...

...

COMMIT;
```

When autocommit is off, the next DML statement implicitly starts a transaction, and that transaction remains uncommitted until you explicitly COMMIT.

If there's an error in the script, the mysql client aborts (unless you use the `--force` option). So it never gets to the COMMIT line. When the client aborts, it rolls back the transaction, and all the preceding DML statements are discarded.

However, there's a risk to doing what you describe, allowing a huge transaction with hundreds of thousands of insert statements. There's a practical limit to the size of a transaction, because binary log files shouldn't be allowed to grow greater than 4GB. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_cache_size

There are a number of bugs in bugs.mysql.com about max_binlog_cache_size. In spite of the warning that it shouldn't be greater than 4GB, the default value of this option is strangely set to 2^64 - 4096. This allows a transaction large enough that will certainly break your binlog (I have experienced this in production, it caused replication to fail).

So here's an alternative strategy: don't try to commit the whole script in one transaction. Instead, import the data into a *different* table (it could be a table of the same name in a different schema). If it fails, drop the table. If it succeeds, then you can migrate the data into the real location you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  My tables can become very large, and I didn't realize there was a limit to the size of the transaction.  And creating a duplicate table can also have it's problems.

So I think what I will do is add a field to my tables that has a unique value for each import.  If the import fails, I will just run a simple Delete statement that will remove any rows that have this value.

Granted it creates a larger table with seemingly unimportant data, but I think that might be the best option for speed and simplicity.

Comment: You might also consider very carefully how important it is to import your whole SQL script as a single transaction.

Comment: Gotcha.  The current way things are done in the code I am using can take hours to import 50,000 records, and usually crashes Apache.  So basically I am modifying the code to write a .sql file instead, then importing the .sql file by passing off the .sql file to the MySQL engine directly.

Comment: You might also consider LOAD DATA INFILE. See my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Comment: Thanks for the information Bill.  I read your presentation and that is really great stuff.  What I need for a complete solution is to do imports of mass amounts of data, into existing tables that may or may not have data that needs to be updated by a selected key.  Also for my customers, I need to support some fields with foreign key lookup.  For instance, I can't have my customers import address and use 11 for the country.  Instead I need to let them put in "US", and have this converted to a fk on import.  Do you know how easy/difficult this would be to accomplish with infile?

Comment: What you describe can't be done directly with LOAD DATA INFILE. You would have to load the raw data into a temporary table and then do a whole lot of data manipulation to map the values to lookup tables in the way you describe. The best way is to write custom code to do this, and load the data row by row, after you have modified the values in the way you want. LOAD DATA INFILE is best used when your data file contains exactly the data you intend to load.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  Yeah unfortunately I am having to do a balancing act between making things simple, convenient, and error free for my customers, and making it fast and not crashing my web server.  Also I forgot to mention that my CSV file templates for the customer are dynamically built from multiple tables that can be dynamically changed, and some of the fields are incremented values based upon a custom mask that the customer creates, based upon the last inserted record.  So there are 2 more wrenches in the gears.  LOL...

Comment: Once I figure out what I want to do, I will put the info. here for other developers to see how hard of a problem this is.